# Use of dots inside brackets to reach variable depth JSON in Jinja2 like ['object.subobject']?

Tags: python, json, flask, jinja2, traversal

It's easy to get a specific variable object from a JSON array in Jinja like:

```
array['somekey']
```

but what if i want to access a value deeper in the nested list like:

```
array['somekey.subkey']
```

These dots inside the square brackets don't work so i can't access a value at a variable position?

Imagine a simple array of objects like the one below. In the template i want to set a variable that defines the path of the object i want to reach so that if the `path` is `somekey1` i get `somevalue1` but if the path is `somekey3.subkey2` i get `subvalue2` like:

**python code**

```
path = 'somekey3.subkey2'
```

**jinja template code**

```
{{ array[path] }}
```

**expected result:**

```
subvalue2
```

**actual result:**

```
no result (nothing gets printed on the screen)
```

**full json array:**

```
[{
    "somekey1": "somevalue1"
}, {
    "somekey2": "somevalue2"
}, {
    "somekey3": {
        "subkey1": "subvalue1",
        "subkey2": "subvalue2"
    }
}]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you'll need a custom filter/function to walk a dictionary of dictionaries using a dotted path (just like you would need with Python too) since `somekey3.subkey2` isn't a key in the object.

Comment: If the JSON code behaved like that, then how would you access a key that *actually contains a period*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my comment says, you'll likely need a custom filter to do dot access – luckily it's not hard to implement:

```
import jinja2


@jinja2.pass_environment
def dot(env: jinja2.Environment, obj, path):
    for key in path.split("."):
        obj = env.getattr(obj, key)  # use same semantics as jinja's own getattr
    return obj


env = jinja2.Environment()

env.filters["dot"] = dot

tpl = env.from_string("""
{{ obj | dot('somekey3.subkey2') }}
""".strip())

print(tpl.render(obj={
    "somekey3": {
        "subkey1": "subvalue1",
        "subkey2": "subvalue2"
    }
}))
```

The output is `subvalue2` as expected.

You could expand this to do index accesses too with judicious use of `isdigit`.